# Redshift DROP TABLE never stops executing

Tags: amazon-redshift

I tried attempted to execute all of the following and the query was still running after over 400 seconds in all cases causing me to have to alt+f4 the navicat program using the created admin account whom is a super user.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.<table> CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.<table>;
DROP TABLE test.<table>;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_TABLE.html says that is proper syntax, what should I be looking at on my cluster to figure out why these queries never execute and just go on forever. I am passing schema because there is a production table in the database with the same name and I cannot delete it, this table exists within the test schema. Is schema inclusion the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article [AWSQuickSolutions: Redshift Table Can’t Be Dropped or Drop Table Hangs](https://medium.com/devopslinks/awsquicksolutions-redshift-table-cant-be-dropped-or-drop-table-hangs-1aff3da223e6) helped me find an answer; I didn't realize there was a pendning backend lock on the table.  Found the lock and removed the pending query.

Comment: I had the same problem, redshift got a lock on unused table... you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens when another process using that table i.e. Deadlock

You can use this query to find out the `pid` of your lock transaction and kill it.

```
select a.txn_owner, a.txn_db, a.xid, a.pid, a.txn_start, a.lock_mode, a.relation as table_id,nvl(trim(c."name"),d.relname) as tablename, a.granted,b.pid as blocking_pid ,datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())/86400||' days '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%86400/3600||' hrs '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%3600/60||' mins '||datediff(s,a.txn_start,getdate())%60||' secs' as txn_duration
from svv_transactions a
left join (select pid,relation,granted from pg_locks group by 1,2,3) b
on a.relation=b.relation and a.granted='f' and b.granted='t'
left join (select * from stv_tbl_perm where slice=0) c
on a.relation=c.id
left join pg_class d on a.relation=d.oid
where  a.relation is not null;

SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<blocking pid>);
```